# Add Suggestions for SearchView when user typing

Tags: kotlin, searchview, search-suggestion

I have a fragment having a toolbar that include a searchview, and I want when users click on it then sending them to another fragment for searching. I'm struggling to implement search suggestions. How can i show suggestions in a recycle view and unhighlight characters that user typed already like google search. I know search dialog as google said in their document, but it only shows suggestions in a drop-down dialog, that not what I want. Thanks for your help. [image]